# Is there any more documentation on WordBasic's FilePrintSetup?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I found the `WordBasic.FilePrintSetup` function when I was searching for a way to change Word's printer without changing Windows' default printer.

Unfortunately I could not find any real documentation on `FilePrintSetup`, even the parameters I found with Google aren't officially documented. (`Printer` and `DoNotSetAsSysDefault`)

So do you know of any documentation? Or do you know additional parameters which are supported by `FilePrintSetup`? (I'm especially interested in setting the tray/paper bin)

**EDIT:** I found out that the paper bin can be selected with `FilePageSetup`, an equally undocumented function. So if you have information about this function, I'd appreciate them, too :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The online help documents the equivalent VBA for WordBasic functions/methods.  These are read-only though.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa264153(office.10).aspx

Edit: ActiveDocument.PrintOut allows you to select a tray for first and following pages.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the printername parameter of the fileprintsetup method is case-sensitive. XP and Win7 don't store server\printernames the same way so you may find a problem when upgrading OS

Answer (score 0):

The previous reply is wrong.  ActivePrinter DOES change the system default printer.  Microsoft's documentation clearly states this.